# Eclipselink problem with subquery in where clause

Tags: jpa, subquery, left-join, eclipselink, criteriaquery

I have the following structure: (I am using eclipselink 2.6.0)

```
@Entity
public class A {

@Id
private double id;
... 

@OneToMany
private List<B> b;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
private List<C> c;

 ...

}

@Entity
public class B {
@Id
private double id;
 
private boolean hidden;
}

@Entity
public class C {
@Id
private double id;

private String label;

private String value;

@ManyToOne
private A a;
}
```

I need to find **A** that are not hidden, and has s1 = value1, s2 = value 2, this is the implementation using criteria:

```
        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<A> cq = cb.createQuery(A.class);
        Root<A> root = cq.from(A.class);
        Join<A, B> property = root.join(A_.b, JoinType.LEFT);
        String currentUser = ctx.getCallerPrincipal().getName();        
        property.on(cb.equal(property.get(B_.creator), currentUser));
        
        C af = new C("value1", "value2");

        Subquery<B> sq = cq.subquery(B.class);
        Root<C> sqRoot = sq.from(C.class);
        sq.where(cb.and(cb.equal(sqRoot.get(C_.A), root),
                cb.equal(sqRoot.get(C_.label), af.getLabel()),
                cb.like(sqRoot.get(C_.value), "%" + af.getValue() + "%")));
        sq.select(sqRoot);

        cq.where(cb.and(
                cb.exists(sq),
                cb.or(cb.isNull(property.get(B_.id)),
                cb.equal(property.get(B_.hidden), false))));
        
        cq.select(root).distinct(true);
```

The generated query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID
FROM B t0, A t1 
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM C t2 WHERE (((t2.A_ID = t1.ID) AND (t2.LABEL = "value1")) AND t2.VALUE LIKE "%value2%"))  AND ((t0.ID IS NULL) OR (t0.HIDDEN = false)))
```

As you can see, the provider ignores the left Join totally as if it doesn't exist! It doesn't do any join between tow tables A and B..
Note that in the JPA JSR, the query should be correct. It also worked as a named query. But I can't use it here since I have lots of changing conditions...

The query should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID
FROM  A t1 LEFT JOIN B t0 ON t1.ID=t0.A_ID AND t0.creator="currentUserValue"
WHERE (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM C t2 WHERE (((t2.A_ID = t1.ID) AND (t2.LABEL = "value1")) AND t2.VALUE LIKE "%value2%"))  AND ((t0.ID IS NULL) OR (t0.HIDDEN = false)))
```

I tried to change eclipseLink to the 2.7.7 release...The query changed a bit, but it still wrong, with no left join between A and B.

I appreciate any help with this problem.